# How to copy data files from one Linux server to another, online, automatically, daily, using a script?

Tags: linux, script, file-transfer

How to move a data files from one Linux server to another in an online Internet environment, automatically daily, using a script?

Answer (score 1):

Use [cron](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cron) to invoke [rsync](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/rsync) in order to transfer/sync files over [SSH](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ssh).

Comment: @Aman: If you really mean "move" (as in `mv`) rather than "copy" (as in `cp`), `rsync` has an option `--remove-source-files`